# Scope of array in nested function

Tags: javascript, nested, scope

I have a class HashTable containing a method addItem returning true if an item did not exist and has been added succesful (I checked it is working).

At the top of the function below a new object of HashTable will be created.
A nested function should use the addItem method of this object hashTable.
Unfortunally there is a problem with scope. Inside the nested function hashTable will not be coloured blue while editing and (indeed) at runtime a message appears stating that the addIten method does not exist.

```
function getHashTableFolders_(folder)
{
   var hashTable = new HashTable();

   function getFolderCollection_(folder)
   { // Recursively fill the hashTable
      if (hashTable.addItem(folder) === true)
      { 
         var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
         var numSubFolders = subFolders.length;
         for (var i=0; i<numSubFolders; i++) getFolderCollection_(subFolders[i]); 
      }
   } 

   getFolderCollection_(folder); // Start the process

   return hashTable;
}
```

How can I refer the object hashTable in the nested function and use its method addItem?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with scope... works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/fedela/1/edit

Comment: It's working for me too. Could you show the HashTable class code?

Comment: I used the code from // https://script.google.com/d/1qxkczJ4kCF9JiTtJshFqwFTdduoihxAsd1V_h4V-jtwHoWMdpUqi7i_K/edit?usp=drive_web
and added an addItem method  .

Answer (score 0):

You can make this possible, just make hashTable declaration before **

getHashTableFolders_

** function,

```
var hashTable = new HashTable();
function getHashTableFolders_(folder)
{

   function getFolderCollection_(folder)
   { // Recursively fill the hashTable
      if (hashTable.addItem(folder) === true)
      { 
         var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
         var numSubFolders = subFolders.length;
         for (var i=0; i<numSubFolders; i++) getFolderCollection_(subFolders[i]); 
      }
   } 

   getFolderCollection_(folder); // Start the process

   return hashTable;
}
```

Comment: this means that `getHashTableFolders_` will not create a new `HashTable` ( which is what the OP requested ) but use one for every execution

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using the function scope, since you are not redefining `hashTable` inside the inner function, so the scope will use a fallback to the object of the outer scope. http://jsbin.com/fedela/1/edit

(Using a Polyfill for `HashTable` and `folder` since they were not provided by OP ):

```
var HashTable = function( ) {
  var obj =  {
    folders: [],
    addItem: function(x) { obj.folders.push( x.name ); return true; }
  };
  return obj;
};

var a = {
  name: "a",
  getFolders: function() { return [];}
};
var b = getHashTableFolders_({
  name: "b",
  getFolders: function() { return [a]}
});
```

which will result in `b.folders // ["b","a"]`

Answer (score 0):

I copied all the code to a new GAS and (after making a backup) destroyed the old GAS I used for making a library.

With the new GAS it works, so I guess it had something to do with using an earlier version of the library.

Thanks to all for responding so quickly.